# how is absolute path of <a href="..."/> determined?

Tags: html, windows, anchor, href, absolute-path

I have an html deep inside my directory structure inside `c:\`. one line there is this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/s/2036/21/2/_/download/superbatch/css/batch.css" media="all">
```

When I hover over the link, it shows `file:///C:/s/2036/21/2/_/download/superbatch/css/batch.css` as the link address. I want it to interpret to actual location which is `file:///C:/Users/name/folder1/...some folders/s/2036/21/2/_/download/superbatch/css/batch.css`

What changes are needed to make?

***EDIT***: there are several files containing relative links so I can't just edit each and every of them.

***P.S***: please change the title to something better if this one is not expressive enough.

Comment: @RoyiNamir In the title. The OP does say there are several files with relative URLs, and the `<link>` here was just one example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I had to put the files inside a webserver's htdocs folder. I was kinda hoping for a different solution

Answer (score 5):

If your HTML file is at `C:\Users\name\folder1\...some folders\`, you can just remove the leading slash to make it a relative path.

Otherwise you have to prefix the address with `file:///C:/Users/name/folder1/...some folders` to keep it absolute.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./s/2036/21/2/_/download/superbatch/css/batch.css" media="all">
```

Note the `.` (dot) at the begining, which means its a relative path, starting at the current executing directory of the document/the file.

Comment: Or `href="s/2036/21/2/_/downl..`, i.e. remove the `/` to turn it into a relative URL

Comment: @AaronDigulla This is bad practise IMO. If i would use this as a common way and someday have a url like `example.com?id=1`, the path would be `id=1s/2036/21/2...`. So I'll try to never get into something like this. ;) But this is some sort of common mistakes and you're right, of course.

Comment: Uh...what are you talking about? If you have queries and references, you need to strip them first, of course. URLs aren't strings, after all (even though most people use them like strings ...)

Answer (score 0):

`First` - I dont see any anchor in your example.

`Second` , it will work only in IE.

you have to access the item through `UNC` ---> `\\myShare\lalala`

here is a working example :

```
 <a type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="\\dev-8\c$\1.txt" >fsdfsd</a>
```

where <kbd>dev-8</kbd> is the name of my computer.

create 1.txt file in your root - and it will work.